# Ionic Angular - Access body selector in page scope

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic7

I need to access the "body" selector in my .scss file. However, I can't access the body selector within the page scope, only in the global.scss or variables.scss files. Is there a way to do this?

I'm trying to change the color of a div when in dark mode (using the 'dark' class on body). Since it's specific to the page, I don't want to add it to a global file.

Like:

**page.scss:**

```
body.dark .whatever-class {
    color: yellow
}
```

**page.html:**

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="whatever-class">
        some text
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**page.component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page',
  templateUrl: './page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.scss'],
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ::ng-deep to style the body selector.

```
::ng-deep body.dark .whatever-class {
    color: yellow
}
```

Note: Applying the ::ng-deep pseudo-class to any CSS rule completely disables view encapsulation for that rule. Any style with ::ng-deep applied becomes a global style.